# Match a pattern inside a column and show only matching part

Tags: awk

I'm trying to write a awk command to find a match inside a specific column and show only the matching data in that column along with other columns. Omit other data in that column.

Please see the below sample, what I need to do is keep only the 8 digit number in the 3rd(discard other data in that column)

```
name,age,notes
james,27, contact me via 47382929
alan,38,hi how are you?
jerry,,736n12345678
guy,20,23542221-321 is number.
```

I tried several command including following

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{/[0-9]{8}/{ print $0 }' 

awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{/[0-9]{8}/, $3) }1'

awk -F ',' '$3~/[0-9]{8}/' 

awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{match($3,/[0-9]{8}/) }1'
```

But non of them were succeeded. I need a awk command to get following output

```
name,age,notes
james,27,47382929
alan,38,
jerry,,12345678
guy,20,23542221
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if that column contained a 9-digit number like `bob,foo,123456789` - should 8 digits match or not? If they should, would that be at the start or end of the 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. Just need to update the value of `$3` with the captured result. Works with any Awk version

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } 
     NR > 1 { 
       if (match($3,/[0-9]{8}/)) { 
         $3 = substr($3, RSTART, RLENGTH) 
       } 
       else $3 = "" 
     }1
' file
```

You could use other built-ins to extract the numeric part of `$3`, but the key here is to update back the result of those methods back.

Comment: Regarding "Works with any Awk version" - it'll work with any POSIX awk but not any awk. One of the 2 functional awks on Solaris (`nawk` or `/usr/xpg[46]/bin/awk` - I don't remember which) doesn't understand RE intervals like `{8}` for example and neither do older versions of GNU awk without the `--re-interval` or `--posix` argument.

Answer (score 6):

Another variation on the command using `match()` can be done making use of the 3rd array parameter to `match()` as:

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR>1{$3 = (match ($3,/[0-9]{8}/,arr)) ? arr[0]  :""}1' file
```

(where the return of `match()` is used as the condition in the ternary to set `$3` to either the matched 8-chars or the empty-string if no match was made)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR>1{$3 = (match ($3,/[0-9]{8}/,arr)) ? arr[0] : ""}1' file
name,age,notes
james,27,47382929
alan,38,
jerry,,12345678
guy,20,23542221
```

(Note: the `array` argument to `match()` is a `GNU awk` extension -- thanks Ed!)

Answer (score 3):

it's better to use, `gsub` function in AWK to remove all non-digit characters from the 3rd column, check this out:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } NR>1 { gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $3) } 1' file.csv
```

output

```
name,age,notes
james,27,47382929
alan,38,
jerry,,73612345678
guy,20,23542221321
```

Comment: That's not the expected output for `jerry` or `guy` as it's concatenating separate numbers by removing the non-digits between them.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` solution.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
match($0,/(^[^,]*,[^,]*,).*([0-9]{8})/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[2]
  next
}
match($0,/(^[^,]*,[^&,]*,)/,arr){
  print arr[1]
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Pretty slick use of `match()` twice with the array. Took me a minute to sort out how you did it. I like it.

Comment: I don't think there should be a `&` in the 2nd regexp `match($0,/(^[^,]*,[^&,]*,)/,arr){` but if there should then please edit your answer to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is another alternative using `sed`:

```
sed -E '1b; s/(([^,]*,){2}).*([0-9]{8}).*/\1\3/; t; s/(([^,]*,){2}).*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
name,age,notes
james,27,47382929
alan,38,
jerry,,12345678
guy,20,23542221
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gensub()`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1&&NF>=3{n=gensub(/(.*)([0-9]{8})(.*)/,"\\2",1,$3); $3=(n!=$3 ? n : "")}1' file
name,age,notes
james,27,47382929
alan,38,
jerry,,12345678
guy,20,23542221
```